# Steering assistance subdomain, How should .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdomain

Steering assistance subdomain

The original URL:

```
http://domain.com/index.php?cat=cats&id=12&url=stackoverflow
```

The rewritten URL:

```
http://cats.domain.com/12/stackoverflow.html
```

How should .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*).html /index.php?cat=%1&subcat=$1&url=$2 [L]
```

The original URL:

```
http://domain.com/index.php?cat=cats&subcat=subcats&url=stackoverflow
```

The rewritten URL:

```
http://cats.domain.com/subcats/stackoverflow.html
```